# Angular Testing: fails to resolve all parameters for Store: (?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to declare my ngrx/Store into the spec file for testing a container component. So I import the store first and inside the beforeEach do the following:

```
      import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';

       beforeEach(async(() => { 
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              declarations: [NotificationsComponent, NotificationsDevicesComponent, 
               ToArrayPipe, OrderByDate, TimezoneFormatPipe],
              providers: [{ provide: Store, useClass: Store }]
            })
              .compileComponents().then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NotificationsComponent);
                component = fixture.componentInstance;
                el = fixture.debugElement;

                fixture.detectChanges();
              });
          }));
```

But I got the error from the heading fails to resolve all parameters for Store: (?, ?, ?).

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: The `cannot resolve parameters for foo: (?, ?)` usually means your dependency injection is not working properly (circular dependencies, bad imports, bad exports, etc). The question marks will indicate the dependencies. Sometimes it'll be like `(FooService, BarService, ?)`, which means the third dependency is the one with the problem.

Comment: Try importing the 3 services they you're trying to inject into `Store` directly from their file, not from a barrel, if that's what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `ngrx` and tested `store`

Here are the steps I followed -

1. Imported `StoreModule` and `Store`

   ```
   import { StoreModule, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
   ```
2. Imported my reducers

   ```
   import { reducers } from './reducers';
   ```
3. Added `StoreModule` in my `TestBed`

   ```
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     imports: [
       StoreModule.forRoot({
         categories: reducers // My reducers
       })
     ],
   ```
4. Defined `store` variable

   ```
   let store: Store<CategoryState>;
   ```
5. Initialized `store`

   ```
   beforeEach(() => {
     store = TestBed.get(Store);

     spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();

     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CategoryListComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;
     fixture.detectChanges();
   });
   ```
6. After that you can use `store` in your test cases.

Comment: The error has gone, although I needed to replace the `StoreModule.forRoot({})`  with `StoreModule.provideStore({})` as it does not seem that the StoreModule has `forRoot` method. Also, do you know why angular throws random errors in general? Like `TypeError: this.store.map is not a function` before even test anything? Many thanks

Comment: You are using the older version of `@ngrx`. In latest version, they have replaced `provideStore` with `forRoot`. This is not a random error. In angular 2 , errors have been simplified. As for example, it if says `this.store.map` is not a function. Then you must look into your `store`. It doesn't holds the correct values.

Comment: Thanks man, I ended up upgrading everything and it seems to work partially. Do you know, although why I got error like: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'X' of undefined` where `undefined` is basically the `this.XMap$ = store.select(state => state.storeData.X);`

Comment: Your `store.select` is probably not working properly. You can use `selectors` for selecting data from `store`. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md is the link for how to use selectors.